# How to globally override method in Perl

Tags: perl, overriding

I am forced to use old version of Apache2::Cookie class which contains bug in method fetch().
I tried to override method in startup script, but it doesn't work later in other modules than startup script:

```
local *Apache2::Cookie::fetch = sub { ... }
```

How to override method globally for all other modules?

Comment: Well, it won't. Because you've defined it as `local` to the current scope.

Comment: Btw, is using a glob preferred over `sub Apache2::Cookie::fetch { ... }`?

Comment: without local doesn't work too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: err, it seems that override is done, but getting new error: Usage: APR::Request::Cookie::Table::cookie_class($table, $class): class main is not derived from APR::Request::Cookie

Comment: @Сухой27 you can always use https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Override and have neither of those two :)

Comment: @lemur that sounds like what you did in your overwritten sub produces an object that doesn't have `APR::Request::Cookie` in its `@ISA`.

Comment: yes, there was another error in overrided code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Sobrique pointed out in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32629096/how-to-globally-override-method-in-perl/32629783#comment53107572_32629096), the `local` is definitely an issue. But not the only one.

You need to load the pacakge first before you do this. Perl will take the last definition of the sub, just like the last assigned value will be the value of a variable.

```
my $foo;
$foo = 1;
$foo = 3;
print $foo; # 3, obviously
```

The same goes for your overwriting.

```
*Apache2::Cookie::fetch = sub { ... }; # note ... is valid syntax
require 'foo';

$cookie = Apache2::Cookie->new; # not sure if that is correct

# in foo.pm
use Apache2::Cokie; # this will overwrite your implementation
```

Loading modules in Perl works with `%INC`, a super-global hash that keeps track of which files have been loaded. If you `use` a file twice, it only gets loaded and parsed the first time. The second time, it will only call `import` on the package.

So the trick is to load Apache2::Cookie first, so it's already parsed when the real code loads it again.

```
use Apache2::Cookie;
BEGIN {
  *Apache2::Cookie::fetch = sub { ... };
}
require 'foo'; # or use, no matter

$cookie = Apache2::Cookie->new; # not sure if that is correct

# in foo.pm
use Apache2::Cokie; # now this won't overwrite your implementation
```

Now Perl already has the file loaded, and the package installed in its guts. Then you overwrite the sub. Then it gets not loaded again and your fix is still intact when it gets called.

Comment: Thank you for pointing outt he copy/paste mistake, @TheSidhekin